# On Click Pop up in input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

Everyone I am very new to javascript I tried lots of things to achieve this task but I won't able to do this.
My Html Code is:

```
<div class="row  lcf-form">
   <div class="col-xs-4">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="All India">
    </div>
   <div class="col-xs-6">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Adds Near You">
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
 </div>
```

My Js Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var started;
  function showLightBox()
   { 
    if (started) return;
    started = setTimeout(function(){
    Lightbox.start(document.getElementById('firstImage'));
    started;
     },500);
   }
   function stopShowLightBox(){
   if (started) {
    clearTimeout(started)
    started = 0;
   }
  }
</script>
```

I follow this link [popup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30042933/on-click-pop-up-not-working) but its not working for me.

I want when I enter my cursor a simply popup div open for input text.

Comment: i used the click events and jquerry

Comment: Ok, where's the code?

Comment: Check this http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp

Comment: Better yet, drop W3Fools and get the good habit of looking at official documentation: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

Comment: I'm just curious, how do you think your functions will be invoked from the html form? I don't event talk about your `started` variable which is not initialised as `boolean` value. P.S. you have mentioned in tags jQuery library but you are using pure, native JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are not calling the **onClick** Event , Just Simply call the ShowLightBox() function.

```
<div class="col-xs-4">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="All India">
</div>
```

Instead Of This You use this:

```
<div class="col-xs-4">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="All India" onClick="showLightBox()">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just Simply add the onclick Event where you want to call the function

Try This

```
<div class="col-xs-4">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="All India" onClick="showLightBox()">
</div>
```

Comment: _I want when i enter my cursor..._ - If i understand OP requriment, than `onClick` event is definitely wrong event listener.